# $and and $or from two collections in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I would like to process data from two collections. 
There are **apple and lime collection in fruit db**. I would like to query category:O and category:W in apple, and then validate which is active last 3 days from apple collection. 
From that result, I'm going to find value<30 in lime collection. 
How would I get this query? I m still learning Mongodb!

This is my two queries

```
db.apple.find({$or: [{"category": "W"},{"category": "O"}]})
db.apple.find({active: {"$gte": new Date()}})
```

Comment: Could you please post one sample document for both collections?

Comment: ` > db.apple.find().pretty()` 
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("56a5ca08a678e83e0db438ae"),
        "category" : "W",
        "active" : ISODate("2016-01-25T13:38:55.928Z"),
        
}

Comment: > db.lime.find().pretty()
{
        "_id" : ObjectId("5766dc58a678e826f246178f"),
        "value" : "NumLong(29)
}

Comment: _'From that result, I'm going to find value<30 in lime collection'_ 
 What is the link between these 2 collections?

Comment: Yes, There's a field in both collection (I can't share it details because of confidential) Let's assume there's no_id in both collections. Thanks

Comment: Hi. I believe it's necessary for us to understand the link between both the collections. Please edit your question & share us sample documents from both the collections and any common fields in them. You need not provide confidential values; just the structure of the documents should do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of a lookup to join apple to lime. This must be done with the mongo aggregation framework.

Something like the following will be required:

```
db.apple.aggregate(
{
    "$match": {
        "category": { $in: ["W", "O"] },
        "active": { $gte: new Date() }
    }
},
{
    "$lookup": {
       from: "lime",
       localField: "no_id",
       foreignField: "no_id",
       as: "lime"
    }
}
)
```

Note that for each apple that matched, an array of limes will be returned where lime.no_id matches apple.no_id. They will be returned as an array of nested documents.